# Regular expression to remove <p> tags from around img elements

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regex to convert all

```
<p><img /></p>
```

to simply

```
<img />
```

The img tags will be fully populated such as

```
<img src="/file.jpg" width="1" height="2" />
```

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Since HTML can be very malformed, you should use an HTML parser, **not** regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if there is nothing else on the line except the three tags. Let me know if you want it explained further.

```
$str = "<p><img src=\"/file.jpg\" width=\"1\" height=\"2\" /></p>"
$replaced = preg_replace ( "/<p[^>]*?>(<img[^>]+>)<\/p>/" , "$1" , $str )
```

Comment: That won't even begin to work. All you did was match the literal string `"<p><img src="/file.jpg" width="1" height="2" /></p>"`. I think it's safe to assume the original poster was not trying to match that literal string.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard, I'm sorry, what do you mean? my pattern and replacement strings will match anything in the form "<p><img></p>". I only took his exact string as an example of how to use it.

Comment: no problem, glad it helps. :) I'm curious why I was downvoted twice though. anyone want to enlighten me?

Comment: @jb: I didn't vote you down but I do think this approach has limitations. In addition to it only working when there is nothing else on the line, as you pointed out, it would fail in the rare case where `">"` appeared within one of the attribute values. And this doesn't even get into other ways HTML can be malformed. Just my opinion, FWIW.

Comment: @Jonathan, oh, I see, that is a valid problem with this approach.

Comment: @Kevin `$str` is just a string example, not the regex pattern

Comment: The main problem is that **RegEx are not suggested for parsing HTML!**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I'm dreadfully sorry for my previous comment. I'm rather overtired and did not parse your answer correctly at all. I'm actually rather mystified as to why someone even upvoted it. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Oscar, I know! I always see the words "regex" and I jump to solve the puzzle, then remember that the correct way is to use HTML parsers. I'll try to slow my horses so I won't be adding to the problem next time.